# Как с камеры передать фото на второй view?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Скажите пжлт весь интернет облазил!
Камера реализована так:

```
- (IBAction)cameraPressed:(id)sender {
UIAlertView*alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload a photo" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Take a photo",@"Chose existing", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[alert show];
}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    UIImagePickerController*imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

    if([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(isCameraDeviceAvailable:)])
    { 
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront])
        {
            imagePicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        }
    }

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion: NULL];
}
if (buttonIndex == 2) {
    UIImagePickerController*imagePicker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker2.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker2 animated:YES completion: NULL];
}
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:        (NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage*image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[_imageView1 setImage:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Comment: Вышел из положения нажатием кнопки перешел на другой View и при загрузке его сразу запускается камера( в дидлоуд положил 
    UIAlertView*alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upload a photo" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Take a photo",@"Chose existing", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[alert show]; ............

Comment: На другой контроллер чтоб когда сфоткался, фотка открывала на xib файле!